# Extracting clusters from seaborn clustermap

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, seaborn, dendrogram

I am using the `seaborn clustermap` to create clusters and visually it works great (this [example](http://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/structured_heatmap.html) produces very similar results).

However I am having trouble figuring out how to programmatically extract the clusters.  For instance, in the example link, how could I find out that 1-1 rh, 1-1 lh, 5-1 rh, 5-1 lh make a good cluster?  Visually it's easy.  I am trying to use methods of looking through the data, and dendrograms but I'm having little success

**EDIT**  Code from example:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(font="monospace")

df = sns.load_dataset("brain_networks", header=[0, 1, 2], index_col=0)
used_networks = [1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17]
used_columns = (df.columns.get_level_values("network")
                          .astype(int)
                          .isin(used_networks))
df = df.loc[:, used_columns]

network_pal = sns.cubehelix_palette(len(used_networks),
                                    light=.9, dark=.1, reverse=True,
                                    start=1, rot=-2)
network_lut = dict(zip(map(str, used_networks), network_pal))

networks = df.columns.get_level_values("network")
network_colors = pd.Series(networks).map(network_lut)

cmap = sns.diverging_palette(h_neg=210, h_pos=350, s=90, l=30, as_cmap=True)

result = sns.clustermap(df.corr(), row_colors=network_colors, method="average",
               col_colors=network_colors, figsize=(13, 13), cmap=cmap)
```

How can I pull what models are in which clusters out of `result`?

**EDIT2**  The `result` does carry with it a `linkage` in with the `dendrogram_col` which I THINK would work with [fcluster](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster.html).  But the threshold value to select that is confusing me.  I would assume that values in the heatmap that are higher than the threshold would get clustered together?

Answer (score 25):

While using `result.linkage.dendrogram_col` or `result.linkage.dendrogram_row` will currently work, it seems to be an implementation detail. The safest route is to first compute the linkages explicitly and pass them to the `clustermap` function, which has `row_linkage` and `col_linkage` parameters just for that.

Replacing the last line in your example (`result =` ...) with the following code gives the same result as before, but you will also have `row_linkage` and `col_linkage` variables that you can use with `fcluster` etc.

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy

correlations = df.corr()
correlations_array = np.asarray(df.corr())

row_linkage = hierarchy.linkage(
    distance.pdist(correlations_array), method='average')

col_linkage = hierarchy.linkage(
    distance.pdist(correlations_array.T), method='average')

sns.clustermap(correlations, row_linkage=row_linkage, col_linkage=col_linkage, row_colors=network_colors, method="average",
               col_colors=network_colors, figsize=(13, 13), cmap=cmap)
```

In this particular example, the code could be simplified more since the correlations array is symmetric and therefore `row_linkage` and `col_linkage` will be identical.

*Note:* A previous answer included a call to `distance.squareshape` according to what the code in seaborn does, but that [is a bug](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/pull/621).

Comment: Hey @Marcel M, wouldn't you want to use a "dissimilarity matrix" instead of a correlation matrix? Like `1 - np.abs(correlations)` or something?

Comment: @O.rka Passing correlations to `sns.clustermap()` comes from the seaborn example quoted in the question, which I just copied. Both versions compute distances between correlations, so in the end distances are in fact used, but I admit I don’t know how much sense it makes to do so (I don’t know why the seaborn example does so). In my own project, I use distances directly.

Answer (score 8):

You probably want a new column in your dataframe with the cluster membership. I've managed to do this from assembled snippets of code stolen from all over the web:

```
import seaborn
import scipy

g = seaborn.clustermap(df,method='average')
den = scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram(g.dendrogram_col.linkage,
                                         labels = df.index,
                                         color_threshold=0.60)  
from collections import defaultdict

def get_cluster_classes(den, label='ivl'):
    cluster_idxs = defaultdict(list)
    for c, pi in zip(den['color_list'], den['icoord']):
        for leg in pi[1:3]:
            i = (leg - 5.0) / 10.0
            if abs(i - int(i)) < 1e-5:
                cluster_idxs[c].append(int(i))

    cluster_classes = {}
    for c, l in cluster_idxs.items():
        i_l = [den[label][i] for i in l]
        cluster_classes[c] = i_l

    return cluster_classes

clusters = get_cluster_classes(den)

cluster = []
for i in df.index:
    included=False
    for j in clusters.keys():
        if i in clusters[j]:
            cluster.append(j)
            included=True
    if not included:
        cluster.append(None)

df["cluster"] = cluster
```

So this gives you a column with 'g' or 'r' for the green- or red-labeled clusters. I determine my color_threshold by plotting the dendrogram, and eyeballing the y-axis values.

Comment: This isn't going to work on bigger data where that are more groups than colours since (for example) green will repeat itself this will group colours.

Comment: For more details how this code works, one can see the "original" post here: `http://www.nxn.se/valent/extract-cluster-elements-by-color-in-python`

Comment: @Dataman It's best that the original author gets credit, I surely had lost the original source by the time I had posted my snippet, and don't remember if I had made any significant changes to the original before posting.